# Using Composer on HLF, is it possible to have several JS files and import / require them?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Using Hyperledger Composer, is it possible to have more than one js logic file, for example to group functions, and also to import npm packages?

Our business network runs fine but we would like to use extra packages - however `require` or `import` are undefined at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO - you can't use require or import.

YES - you can separate your transactions into separate files within the `lib` folder of the project.  They just need to retain the .js extension.